# Designing isolated flyback with multiple outputs

Tags: dc-dc-converter, isolation, flyback

UPDATE: as suggested, I split this question into separate parts (links below). I left the last one here. It is so silly I am rather proud of it ;)

UPDATE 2: it seems that breaking one post into multiple questions only annoyed people, which wasn't my intention. Please, accept my apologies for the spam.

Over past few weeks I've been reading LT datasheets and application notes and everything I googled on the web. While I think I am getting the basics right, some rather unexpected questions popped up and I could not find definite answer to them. I'd appreciate any help or even a point to the reading material I could use, something like "flyback for dummies" would be the best :)

[Switch voltage drop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/376951/)

[Isolated secondary coils](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/376953/)

[Calculating minimum primary turns](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/376955/) - Answered

[Wire selection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/376958/) - Answered

[DZ snubber](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/376959/) - Answered

Final question, if the load draws pulsed power and output caps are sufficiently big can I use average load current for the purpose of DC-DC calculations?
For example if output is modulated at 50% duty, can I use 1/2 of its current as secondary coil current?

Comment: You should read the 'help' section on asking questions. You have many questions that would take a book to answer. Please narrow this down to a couple of the most important ones. Surfing the Web with key words can answer a lot of what you ask. As it is right now it is too broad in scope to answer.

Comment: I thought about this before posting and decided that since these all related to essentially same task it would be nice to have them together. And I mentioned that I did spend two weeks looking for the answers before asking. Anyway, if you think this is inappropriate way to ask questions I am sure someone will close it eventually.

Comment: Ahem...It is the number of questions you are asking about a very complex device-a multi output flyback power supply. Only a skilled engineer would attempt it, and your many questions tell us you have no skills. `I think I am getting the basics right.` You need to be far beyond that to even consider building a flyback SMPS.

Comment: Isn't it the point of hobby to learn something?

Comment: Granted, but start small, not by building the equivalent of a spaceship or robot. The board layouts are crucial, so build a much simpler buck/boost converter first.

Comment: Sorry, I can't agree with that. The number of components in flyback is not that different from other kinds. The board layout is equally important for either of them. The rest are just formulas to use, and they are no more complicated for flyback than say, for boost. Sorry, it is not a rocket science you make it up to be. I might not design most efficient DC-DC in the universe but I am sure I can make something that would produce voltage on the output. Hopefully with the help of people on this forum, by myself if I must.

Comment: Bringing an attitude to this site is not good. We know of what we speak. You have too much wishful thinking, and no skills. We are not joking when we suggest you start small, and work your way up. Btw, a SMPS is close to rocket science.

Comment: Forgive me for pointing this out, but so far all you speak of is my inadequacy. Flyback converter is a new thing for me, that is why I am reading documentation and asking questions.

Comment: Flyback is far more challanging than what meets the eye. Start with buck and forward to learn.