# How I can reduce drop voltage?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

as shown in fig.below the primary resistance 1ohm
and the drop voltage is large when applied 12v only few millivolt applied on transformer
how i can reduce it ?

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of R4? What voltage is applied to the left end of R1?

Comment: What's the waveform at the gate of Q1? Constant or AC?

Comment: voltage applied on R1 3V pulse

Comment: @ThePhoton Q1 pluse 3volt AC

Comment: @ElliotAlderson voltage applied on R1 3V pulse .not R4 its R2=4.7 10W

Comment: IRFZ44N Rds(on) is specified at 10 V, and Vgs(th) might be as high as 4 V. You need a bigger pulse on the gate (or a different MOSFET).

Comment: Say you want 1 A through the transformer primary. Then you need to apply ~ \$4\ V + (1\ A)(4.7\ \Omega)\approx 10\ V\$ to the Q1 gate to be sure of getting it.

Comment: do u mean 10 v pulse ? @ThePhoton

Comment: ~10 V peak voltage in your pulse to get 1 A peak through the primary.

Comment: Swap the positions of R4 and Q1 (unless it is supposed to be a current sense resistor, in which case reduce it to a small fraction of an ohm).  Figure out the path of your recirculation current.  And of course make sure that your expectations of behavior when passing pulses rather than a steady AC excitation through a transformer are appropriate.

Comment: @ChrisStratton stay R 4,7 10 w?OR Change ?

Comment: That is unknowable from the information provided.  **WHAT IS THE PURPOSE OF R4????**  - without knowing that, no one can make any useful suggestion about it, beyond the fact that a 4.7 ohm resistor in the position you have drawn it is **UNWORKABLY WRONG**.  If it's part of the load, it needs to be above the FET with the FET source grounded.  If it's a sense resistor the *resistance* inserted between the source and ground needs to be orders of magnitude smaller or it will prevent you from controlling the FET.

Comment: @ChrisStratton its for reduce current to protect transformer from burn

Comment: Then it's part of the load and should be between the FET and the transformer or between the transformer and the positive supply.  In the position where you have drawn it, the circuit cannot work properly as your gate drive would have to overcome the V=IR drop on the resistor.

Comment: Is this a real circuit you are trying to build, or just a simulation?

Comment: real circuit to get high voltage @BruceAbbott

Comment: @emad: Think: If you were able to turn Q1 on fully, (1) what current would flow? (2) What would be the voltage drop across R4? (3) Then what would be the voltage between Q1 gate and source? (4) Would the MOSFET still be on then? Try and answer all the questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic problems with your circuit.

1. The IRF44Z needs 10V Gate drive to turn on fully. To work with 3.3V you need a FET specified to operate with 2.5V Gate drive. Alternatively you could use a Gate driver IC such as the [TC1426](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/TC1426).
2. Current flowing through the 4.7Ω resistor causes a voltage drop that subtracts from the Gate drive voltage, preventing the FET from fully turning on. You should move the resistor to the positive supply side of the transformer.

Once those problems are fixed you have another; when the FET turns off the magnetic energy stored in the inductance of the transformer primary winding will cause a large voltage spike that could destroy the FET. This will be reduced if you put a suitable load on the secondary to absorb the energy, but not completely eliminated because the transformer has some [leakage inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_inductance).

To limit flyback voltage to a safe level you should add a [Zener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode) or [TVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-voltage-suppression_diode) diode and/or [snubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber) network. An example of using a Zener and snubber is discussed in this Stack Exchange question:-

[Designing flyback converter - DZ snubber](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/376959/designing-flyback-converter-dz-snubber)